Non-trivial theorem about polygonals
Last year at the beginning of a linear algebra course my professor made a quite lengthy introduction on Euclidean geometry, in particular he explained why a more rigorous foundation is needed and introduced Hilbert's axioms. He stated the following theorem, explaining that although it seems obvious, it is indeed a profound and delicate result. Before continuing, please keep in mind that English is not my first language, so I apologise if the lexicon and notation used are imprecise. 

Theorem: Let $\pi$ be a plane and $C$ a closed and simple polygonal $P_0;P_1;\dots;P_n$.
Therefore (thesis) $\pi-C=I(C)\sqcup E(C) $ (i.e.: interior and exterior) such that  $P;Q$ belong to the same region $\iff$ there is a polygon between $P$ and $Q$ in $\pi-C$.

He also provided us with the following lemma 

Lemma: For all polygons $C$ like in the statement of the theorem there exists $i$ so that considered the triangle $T$, whose vertices are $P_{i-1}$, $P_i$, and $P_{i+1}$, then $T\cap C = P_{i-1}P_i \cup P_{i+1}P_i$ (i.e. two segments).

He told us to prove both as an exercise, suggesting we prove the lemma from the axioms (please note at this point he had only talked about the incidence and order axioms) and also suggesting we prove the theorem by induction, considering a triangle as basis of the induction. 
He never talked about this theorem again during the course, but since I am a proof lover I have been looking for a proof for a while and even tried to prove it myself, but my attempt is so far incomplete and it is probably wrong, therefore I would really appreciate if someone came up with a solution.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Foundations-level discussions can be tricky, since different authors often present axioms in different ways to suit pedagogical agendas and whatnot. Also, it's very easy to invoke results that inadvertently use axioms that are not yet "in play" for the given context. So, please provide a reference to Hilbert's Incidence and Order axioms that matches how you were taught them; please also note any helpful propositions/theorems/results derived in class, so that readers can avoid duplicating that effort or explaining things you already understand. ... Good luck!

"I have [...] even tried to prove [the result] myself, but my attempt is so far incomplete and it is probably wrong" ... Please edit the question to include your attempt. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) It may be possible that a simple nudge (or correction) can lead you to a complete solution of your own. And, again, letting us know what you've tried helps us avoid duplicating your effort (possibly getting just as stuck) or telling you things you already know.

It is polygonal Jordan curve theorem. Proving it from axioms is a daunting task.

The lemma is only true if $C$ itself is not a triangle. I.e., $n > 2$, and there are more than $3$ vertices that are not collinear with their two neighbors.

FYI - the key tool for proving both is Pasch's axiom (Hilbert's II.4). Everything else is pretty much the sort of geometric reasoning you see everywhere, but the very purpose of Pasch's axiom was to prevent lines from "crossing" without actually intersecting. (Contrast with the rational plane $\Bbb Q^2$ where is easy to set up lines that would intersect at a point with an irrational coordinate, and thus in $\Bbb Q^2$ do not intersect at all despite not being parallel.)
